# How can i make a circuit such that output voltage is reduced by golden ratio, using feedback

Tags: voltage, feedback

I want output voltage to equal input voltage divided by phi. Is there a way to use feedback such that i get an exact result? I don't want use numerical convergence with resisters but rather use feedback so as to create the Fibonacci pattern in electronic design.

Comment: An exact result? No, there are always non-ideal effects and tolerances. (e.g. resistor tolerance and tempco, and thermal and 1/f noise.)  You can get close with a non-inverting op-amp and suitable resistors to set the gain.

Comment: Do you want the output to be multiplied by phi or divided by it? Note that phi≈1.618; multiplying by phi would require your circuit to output a higher voltage than it takes as an input.

Comment: Side note: what's the application? Genuinely curious.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to multiply by \$ \phi \$ or divide by \$ \phi \$.

Comment: Probably Charles Spencer just wanted to see if he can identify Fibonacci pattern in electronic design.

Comment: Application is for a control voltage circuit for electronic music. Outputs 1-8 would be input divided by phi successively.  Are well chosen resistors really the better choice? Or would the feedback design somehow lock things in better?

Comment: Well-chosen resistors, or probably resistors and a trim pot seems like the obvious answer. You should buffer each stage with a unity-gain op-amp.

Comment: So a feedback system won't give a more true missle-lock style golden ratio output over a larger range of inputs?

Comment: Charles, if you want to eliminate the numerical convergence approach which is all answers are based on by now, then edit your question in accordance to guess of @soosaisteven. Also this way it will be a great question I think.

Comment: What would be a good way to phrase that?

Comment: All of these solutions are based on the accuracy of feedback resistors. So why not just use resistors to generate your 0.618 divider ratio if that's what you're after?

Comment: If you can get something more accurate than laser-trimmed resistors, you have invented a perfect voltage reference - this would revolutionize the measurement industry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the golden ratio is 1.61803398875 and if you take the reciprocal and add one you get the same number so maybe you could consider using an analogue multiplier to generate the reciprocal of a voltage (call it Vx) such as this: -

[image]

Then add 1 volt to the output using a summing op-amp amp circuit (it will also convert the undesired negative output of the divider circuit to a positive value).

Finally, use negative feedback (another op-amp) to force Vx and Vout+1 to be the same value ergo you have generated the golden ratio but it's analogue so be prepared for errors.

You could, on the other hand just pick resistors that pot a voltage reference down to the precise voltage but where's the fun in that!

Answer (score 2):

While you can't get a truly exact result, the circuit below will give you an approximate result. You could use a trimmer potentiometer to set the value closer, or you could play games with parallel combinations of resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnaS9u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that this assumes you want to do what you said in the text, not what you wrote in the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, there was a brother of the man famous for "Ohm's Law" who wrote about this property of "Continuous Proportions" which later became known as the Golden Ratio.

*The first known use of the [term](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Golden_ratio.html) appears in a footnote in Die reine Elementar-Matematik by Martin Ohm (the brother of Georg Simon Ohm):-)*

the golden ratio is 1/x = (√5 + 1)/2 = 1.6180339887498948482...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK9Pjk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your voltage levels are reasonable (say 1 - 10 volts), you can construct a circuit with ordinary op amps and precision resistors that will have a gain equal to phi. The accuracy will depend on the accuracy of the resistors.  If say 0.005% is not accurate enough, then you could add a trimming pot assuming you have equipment that could measure to the required accuracy.  If your voltage is AC, then the available accuracy will deteriorate depending on the frequency.  At low audio frequencies, you should still be able to achieve accuracy equal to that of the resistors.  At higher frequencies, the effects of parasitic capacitances and inductances will lower the achievable accuracy.  You need to provide more information about your input signal characteristics and the actual accuracy you want before a more detailed answer can be given.